# Rails rename_column changing the column's type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm writing a `down` method in my migration to deal with reverting a migration that replaces a string field with a reference field. Here's the code:

```
class ChangeCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    rename_column :cars, :make_id, :make_id_string
    add_reference :cars, :make, foreign_key: true, optional: true

    Cars.all.each do |car|
      unless car.make_id_string.nil?
        make = Make.find_by(uuid: car.uuid)
        car.make_id = make
      end

      car.save!
    end

    remove_column :cars, :make_id_string
  end

  def down
    add_column :cars, :make_id_string, :string

    Cars.all.each do |car|
      unless car.make.nil?
        car.make_id_string = car.make.uuid
      end

      car.save!
    end

    # at this point :make_id_string -> String

    remove_reference :cars, :make, index: true, foreign_key: true
    rename_column :cars, :make_id_string, :make_id

    # at this point :make_id -> Fixnum
  end
end
```

It seems like when I'm removing the reference, I'm not completely flushing it out so when I replace the `make_id` field, it takes on that `fixnum` type.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have real data in the `make_id_string` I would strongly suggest not to remove it. If you have some bugs in the migration, it would save you. Also reverting the migration would be far easier.
2. If you want to iterate over all models in `Car`, don't use `#each`, because if loads all the cars to memory at once. Use [`#find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) that loads records in batches.

Comment: so you would just leave the data in make_id_string?

Comment: Yes, I'd do it. I would remove all the indexes that points to that column (for performance reasons) and document in the code that this column is deprecated.

Comment: cool that's helpful. but going back to the original question, the problem im running into is when i revert the migration and rename `make_id_string` back to `make_id`, it will change the type of the column to a fixnum instead of retaining the string type it originally has

Comment: Ahh, I found my issue. My migrations were fine, I just needed to restart my rails console to reflect the changes for some reason. thanks for the help man!